# Netbeans - run bash script before running the program?

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-10

might be a stupid question, but I've just started using Netbeans 10 for a C++ project.

When I run/debug the project, I'd need to first execute a bash script which sets up the environment, and then execute the binary (including an argument to be passed):

```
#!/bin/bash
source setup_script.sh
./bin/my_program -c some_argument
```

I've tried just pointing Project Properties -> Run -> Run Command to the .sh file containing this launch script, but that won't do it (the Run / Debug buttons are either greyed our, or it'll tell me it doesnt recognize the executable type).

Is there any way to setup Netbeans to launch my application via this script, or any other way to achieve the same - e.g. setting up some sort of pre-run command that'd execute setup_script.sh in the same session?

Thanks!